# Conditionally multiply values based on names

Tags: r, dplyr

I have one dataframe, something like:

```
d <-
  data.frame(
    col1 = c(7, 8, 9),
    col2 = c(12, 7, 0),
    col3 = c(1, 2, 3)
  )
```

and vector with numbers

```
coefs <-
  c(
    col1  = 4,
    col2  = 6
  )
```

what I need to achieve is IF column name in my df is equal to vector column, then I'd like to multiply it. If column name is different, missing or not equal, then it should remain same.

As an example, for the above data frame and vector, the results should be:

```
result <-
  data.frame(
    col1 = c(28, 32, 36),
    col2 = c(72, 42, 0),
    col3 - c(1, 2, 3)
  )
```

I think that the best approach would be to use mutate_if, but im not sure how to match column names.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this in base R directly

```
d[names(coefs)] <- d[names(coefs)] * as.list(coefs)
d

#  col1 col2 col3
#1   28   72    1
#2   32   42    2
#3   36    0    3
```

Comment: Learned something know (data.frame and list multiplication).

Comment: Do you need the `as.list`? I think you can do it directly `d[names(coefs)] <- d[names(coefs)] * coefs`...?

Comment: @Sotos No, it does not give expected output as it multiples 7 with 4 and 8 with 6 and so on in a recycling way. We can use the double transpose method as well here. `t(t(d[names(coefs)]) * coefs)`

Comment: ahh ok...I did not test that. The double transpose looks awful...

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `sweep()` from `base R`:

```
d[names(coefs)] <- sweep(d[names(coefs)], 2, FUN = "*", coefs)

  col1 col2 col3
1   28   72    1
2   32   42    2
3   36    0    3
```

In general, `dplyr` is not really great for these sweep-like operations. It is because it is not applying one value per column as one would maybe expect, but recycling the values. To illustrate it:

```
d %>%
 mutate_at(vars(names(coefs)), ~ . * coefs)

  col1 col2 col3
1  112  288    1
2  192  252    2
3  144    0    3
```

You see that the first column is 28 * 4, 32 * 6 and then 36 * 4.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good ol' for loop to do the heavy lifting:

```
for (i in colnames(d)) {
  if (any(names(coefs) %in% i)) {
    d[, i] <- d[, i] * coefs[i]
  }
}

> d
  col1 col2 col3
1   28   72    1
2   32   42    2
3   36    0    3
```